# ¿Por qué se dice "sin trampa ni cartón"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, significado

En español existe la expresión *[sin trampa ni cartón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aGlB829#CgBA2Gk)* para indicar que algo no tiene truco ni engaño alguno.

> *Hela aquí que la voy diciendo en palabras crudas, para todos los oídos, comprobable a todos los ojos, sin trampa ni cartón, la noche cierta, la auténtica, que la sirvo y dispongo, que la lanzo y la escupo.*
>
> Vicente Aleixandre, "Ámbito", 1928 (España).

Entiendo que de algo real, que no tiene truco, se diga que "no tiene trampa", pero ¿por qué se dice que tampoco tiene "cartón"?

Comment: Siempre asocié esa expresión al Teatro en el que se utiliza trampas en el suelo para hacer aparecer y desaparecer personajes y el decorado o _atrezzo_ es de cartón.  Es decir, como para decir que es de verdad y no fingido o falso como en el Teatro.

Answer (score 4):

Quizás (pura especulación al no encontrar ninguna fuente) el *cartón* del modismo corresponda a una abreviación de [**cartón piedra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7l5h752)

> 1. loc. adj. Dicho de una cosa: **Falsa, artificial**.

Quedaría así reforzada la ausencia de *trampas* con la ausencias de cosas *falsas o artificiales*.

Entiendo que esto es más un comentario que una respuesta, pero no tengo reputación como para ponerlos.

**Edición:**
La referencia más antigua al modismo que he encontrado es de febrero de 1881, de [*Madrid Cómico*](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002065926&page=8&search=trampa%20cart%C3%B3n&lang=es): "Porque  para fumarse un cigarro del estanco se necesita   consumir por lo  menos un wagón **de los de sin trampa y sin cartón**."

Acabo de encontrar un anuncio del 30/3/1887 de [**La Crónica (Huesca)**](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0026949128&page=13&search=trampa%20cart%C3%B3n&lang=es) que puede indicar un origen diferente (¿quizás literal?) del modismo:

> VENTA DE FÓSFOROS Y РАРEL DE FUMAR
>   de las más acreditada fábricas nacionales y extranjeras
>   PRECIOS ECONÓMICOS
>   Docena de cajas de fósforos  desde 25 céntimos de peseta á 3 pesetas.
>   Frascos de hoja de lata, cerilla extra, peso 250 y 500 gramos, 1 y 2 pesetas.
>   Fósforos por kilos  desde 2 pesetas á 6, **sin trampa ni carton**.

Answer (score 2):

No veo referencias más "oficiales", pero al menos estas dos tienen opiniones que coinciden y me parecen lógicas. [La primera](http://www.magiapotagia.com/showthread.php?t=4344) dice así:

> ... tiene que ver ... con la caza.
>
> Las antiguas trampas de buhoneros, a las que les ponían papel por encima y cubrían con hojas para que los animales cayeran

Y [esta otra](http://realmentemidiario.blogspot.com.co/2011/04/martes-05-de-abril-de-2011.html):

> Referente a esto, podríamos decir que cuando se pone en el campo una trampa para cazar a un animal, ésta se tapa o con hojarasca, si la hay, o con cartón y papeles demenuzados que es lo que más se parece. Es por ello que se la añade la coletilla. Así queda ya mucho más claro que lo que decimos o hacemos es totalmente transparente, sin esconder detrás posibles dobles intenciones.

Answer (score 0):

Como se ha indicado en las otras respuestas, yo también leí en su día que el origen de esa frase proviene de cazadores que hacían las trampas en el monte y que les ponían papel o cartón por encima, y cubrían con hojas, para que los animales cayeran en ellas.

En ocasiones, cazaban alguna pieza "sin trampa ni cartón".

Pero hay expresiones que nunca sabremos su origen real.